# Why is TODO always highlighted in vim?

Tags: vim

I was going through a bash file and I noticed that `TODO` was written twice in the file, and both the instances were highlighted. Why's this? Is it because TODOs are very significant and might avert wastage of time for developers? What's the history behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a syntax element which may be defined (or not) for this particular buffer.

Typically syntax is defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/[filetype].vim`. The relevant command could look like this, for example:

```
syn keyword cTodo contained TODO FIXME XXX
```

Whether such definition is useful or not is subjective, I admit.

You can see all syntax elements defined for the current buffer with `:syntax` command.